# Get a string in the last column using Python

Tags: python, regex, csv

i need to get a string from CSV file, i know that I can use Python but i've been looking for hours but still can't get it. The is the CSV looks like:

```
DATE|CUST|PHONE|EMAIL|NAME|CLASS|QTY|AMOUNT|ID|TRX_ID|BOOKING CODE|PIN

01-02-2013 09:04:16|sdasd|43543|csdfd|Voucher Regular|REGULAR|1|2250000|G001T001|0062013000149|32143000341|MV1011302JSGUCFOM

01-02-2013 09:04:16|sdasd|43543|csdfd|Voucher Regular|REGULAR|2|1200000|G001T001|0062013000149|32143000341|MV4011302CBWDQYOU&MV4011302PVSEVAPJ

01-02-2013 11:01:13|ge|||Voucher Regular|REGULAR|1|600000|G001T001|20000027000005|32143000355|MV4011302UHKMJEEM
```

The string that I want to get is the `PIN` column (the last one); but in each column, there can be multiple PINs, separated by `'&'`.

Thanks for the help, been looking at solving this for hours.

Comment: why python for this? unix `awk` will do it for you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with a csv file, just use the [csv module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html):

```
import csv
from itertools import chain

with open('path/to/your/file.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
  tmp = (r['PIN'].split('&') for r in csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter='|'))
  pins = list(chain.from_iterable(tmp))

for pin in pins:
    print pin
```

Comment: Hi, Dominic thanks, but for the string that concatenate with '&' it still as 1 line,just like this:MV4011302CBWDQYOU&MV4011302PVSEVAPJ. How can i get those as separate line?thanks

Comment: you can call `.split('&')` on each row. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Split on | and get the last entry:

```
pin = line.split('|')[-1]
```

Or more fancy:

```
import csv

with open('bookings.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    bookings = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='|')
    for values in bookings:
        print(values[-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through each line and use something like this:

```
'hello|world|and|noel'.split('|')[-1]
```

to get the last element